# ¿Cómo crear una conexión a una base de datos con PyQt?

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Estoy trabajando con librerías QT en Python 3.5, la idea es introducir los datos a través de una interfaz gráfica, abre la ventana principal, el usuario le da a añadir un libro, se abre una ventana de dialogo, llena los datos correspondientes y sucede que dice "Driver not loaded Driver not loaded". Espero que puedan ayudarme :)

```
import sys, re, subprocess
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog, QGridLayout, QMessageBox, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QSpinBox
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery

#Clase de QMain
class Ventana(QMainWindow):
    """docstring for Ventana"""
    def __init__(self):
        #Iniciar el objeto
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        #Cargar la cfg del archivo .ui en el objeto
        uic.loadUi("mainWindow.ui",self)
        #Establecer conexión a la base de datos MySql
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
        self.db.setHostName("localhost")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("Biblioteca")
        self.db.setUserName("root")
        self.db.setPassword("")

        #Objetos:
        self.agregar = Agregar()

        #Funciones de botones:
        self.btn_Agregar.clicked.connect(self.abrirAgregar)
        self.btn_Salir.clicked.connect(self.Salir)

    #Métodos de las funciones:
    def abrirAgregar(self):
        self.agregar.exec_()

    def Salir(self):
        self.close()

class Agregar(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Agregar.ui",self)
        #Boton cancelar
        self.Cancelar.clicked.connect(self.cancelar)
        #Conexión con MySql
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
        self.db.setHostName("localhost")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("Biblioteca")
        self.db.setUserName("root")
        self.db.setPassword("")
        #Validaciones
        self._Titulo.textChanged.connect(self.validarTitulo)
        self._Autor.textChanged.connect(self.validarAutor)
        self._Editorial.textChanged.connect(self.validarEditorial)
        self._Resumen.textChanged.connect(self.validarResumen)

        #Objetos:

        #Funciones de botones:
        self.btn_Aceptar.clicked.connect(self.Insertar)

    #Validaciones
    def validarTitulo(self):
        _Titulo = self.campoTitulo.text()
        validar = re.match('^[a-z\sáéíóúàèìòùäëïöüñ]+$', _Titulo, re.I)
        if _Titulo == "":
            self._Titulo.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid yellow;")
            return False
        elif not validar:
            self._Titulo.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red;")
            return False
        else:
            self._Titulo.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid green;")
            return True

    def validarAutor(self):
        _Autor = self.campoAutor.text()
        validar = re.match('^[a-z\sáéíóúàèìòùäëïöüñ]+$', _Autor, re.I)
        if _Autor == "":
            self._Autor.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid yellow;")
            return False
        elif not validar:
            self._Autor.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red;")
            return False
        else:
            self._Autor.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid green;")
            return True

    def validarEditorial(self):
        _Editorial = self.campoEditorial.text()
        validar = re.match('^[a-z\sáéíóúàèìòùäëïöüñ]+$', _Editorial, re.I)
        if _Editorial == "":
            self._Editorial.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid yellow;")
            return False
        elif not validar:
            self._Editorial.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red;")
            return False
        else:
            self._Editorial.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid green;")
            return True

    def validarResumen(self):
        _Resumen = self.campoResena.text()
        validar = re.match('^[a-z\sáéíóúàèìòùäëïöüñ]+$', _Resumen, re.I)
        if _Resumen == "":
            self._Resumen.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid yellow;")
            return False
        elif not validar:
            self._Resumen.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red;")
            return False
        else:
            self._Resumen.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid green;")
            return True

    #Insertar datos en una tabla con MySql
    def Insertar(self):
        Estado = self.db.open()
        if Estado == False:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", self.db.lastError().text(), QMessageBox.Discard)
        else:
            Titulo = self.campoTitulo.text()
            Fecha = self.campoFecha.date()
            Autor = self.campoAutor.text()
            Editorial = self.campoEditorial.text()
            Resumen = self.campoResena.text()
            SQL = "INSERT INTO Libros (Titulo, Fecha, Autor, Editorial, Resumen) VALUES (:Titulo, :Fecha, :Autor, :Editorial, :Resumen"
            Consulta = QSqlQuery()
            Consulta.prepare(SQL)
            Consulta.bindValue(":Titulo", Titulo)
            Consulta.bindValue(":Fecha", Fecha)
            Consulta.bindValue(":Autor", Autor)
            Consulta.bindValue(":Editorial", Editorial)
            Consulta.bindValue(":Resumen", Resumen)
            Estado = Consulta.exec_()
            if Estado == True:
                QMessageBox.information(self, "Éxito", "Datos guardados", QMessageBox.Discard)
            else:
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", self.db.lastError().text(), QMessageBox.Discard)

            self.db.close()

    #Métodos de las funciones
    def cancelar(self):
        self.close()

#Instancia para iniciar la aplicación
app = QApplication(sys.argv) #Obligatorio pasar argumentos argv
#Crear el objeto ventana de la clase
_ventana = Ventana()
#Mostrar ventana
_ventana.show()
#Ejecutar
app.exec_()
```

Ahora el nuevo problema que tengo es que dice en la terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.pyw", line 145, in <module>
    _ventana = Ventana()
  File "main.pyw", line 22, in __init__
    self.agregar = Agregar()
  File "main.pyw", line 48, in __init__
    self._Titulo.textChanged.connect(self.validarTitulo())
AttributeError: 'Agregar' object has no attribute '_Titulo'
```

Comment: ¿Que sistema operativo usas?

Comment: GNU/Linux Elementary ¿Pero no debería de funcionar en todos los sistemas por igual?